Overloaded functions have similar conversions
My program will not compile, and give the error overloaded functions have similar conversions. What does this mean and how do I fix it?
struct DynamicInt {
    bool operator==(const DynamicInt&);
};

int main()
{
    DynamicInt a, b;
    return a == b;      // error at this line
}

Demo.

Please post a [mcve]. Remove all the irrelevant stuff to reproduce that specific error.

The code is not able to compile. You lost closing braces, semicolons and delcarations.

@πάνταῥεῖ I just simplified the code so it should be easier to read. Should have all the necessary braces, semi-colons, and declarations. Sill would not compile though, same issue as raised.

@Xmaki The problem isn't about simplifying as you think about it. Follow the exact instructions in that linked article: [mcve]!

@πάνταῥεῖ thanks for the link and tip. I read it. I believe the new edited code posted abides by the MRE it pointed out. The code is short, complete. I have removed all the irrelevant codes. Still the issue exists on my computer. It would not compile at all citing the same issue: "Overloaded functions have similar conversion"

@AviBerger That was a "string" typo on the error message when I copied. But upon checking, everything in the code says "DynamicInt". I corrected the error message typo anyway, thank you.

@πάνταῥεῖ  Dupe: C++20 comparison: warning about ambiguous reversed operator

Just follow the hints in the compiler warnings:
note: mark 'operator==' as const or add a matching 'operator!=' to resolve the ambiguity

and change
bool operator==(const DynamicInt& operand2) const {
                                            ^^^^^

and you get it compiled, https://godbolt.org/z/7vdxjEEv4
